# Disable an input from the microphone while recording audio on Android

Tags: android, audiorecord, android-audiorecord

I'm working with [AudioRecord](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html), when I plug the earphones in my device, it will record both the input sound from the microphone in earphones and the input sound from the  mic in device.

How can I disable the input sound from the microphone programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Scratch previous answer,  FOUND THE SOLUTION!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21735706/5439782

Step 3 is CRUCIAL! Instead of calling default profile on all settings, call it before and store it in Profile. THEN set all the settings you need WITHOUT audio encoder and audio source. Worked for me on unrooted device :)