# how to capture video without audio in android programmatically?

Tags: android, audio, video

I'm just invoking video intent to capture.

`

```
private void dispatchTakeVideoIntent() {
       Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        }
}
```

`

like this. But I need to capture it without Audio.I checked this below link but couldn't found how to resolve
[Android record video without audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920898/android-record-video-without-audio)

Comment: The full code is posted in that thread you linked...it's pretty much just to copy and paste it and it should work?

Comment: go through this eg https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video

Answer (score 0):

Just use the MediaRecorder class to record the video. With media recorder, while setting up the audio and video source just don't set the audio source there. like this.

```
public class MuteVideoRecorderView extends SurfaceView implements
        SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;

    private Camera mCamera;
    private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;

    public CamcorderView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        mHolder.addCallback(this);

        mCamera = Camera.open();
        mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

    }

    public void stop() {
        mRecorder.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        mCamera.unlock();
        mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

        // Here we will not set mRecorder.setAudio(..);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(int, int);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(int);

        mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder.getSurface());


        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
            mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);

        // change for desired output folder
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/mnt/sdcard/test/work");

        try {
            mMediaRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.e("IllegalStateException", e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("IOException", e.toString());
        }
        mMediaRecorder.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply leaving out the `AudioSource` unfortunately doesn't work on Android 10+; `MediaRecorder.prepare()` fails. I've been searching without success for a method which works on this API level.